How to wait until an element disappears?
==> autoremove.html <==
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Delayed Deletion</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="myButton">Click me!</button>
    <script>
      var button = document.getElementById("myButton");
      setTimeout(function() {
        button.remove();
      }, 3000);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>

==> main.js <==
#!/usr/bin/env node
// vim: set noexpandtab tabstop=2:

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const browserURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:9222';

const url = process.argv[2]

let browser;
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.connect({browserURL});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);
    await page.waitForFunction(() => !document.querySelector('#myButton'));
    console.log('there');   
    await page.close();
})()
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
    .finally(
        () => browser?.disconnect()
    )

I have the above node js program and html code.
When I run it like the following, I'd like the program to finish when the element is removed from the browser. But the program hangs there.
./main.js file://"$PWD"/autoremove.html

How can I wait until an element is removed from the browser?

Hey there. This is your fourth question today, and the previous 3 are still unresolved. Can you follow up and let me know whether my answers to those 3 questions worked for you before asking more? It's pretty frustrating to put work into your questions, get ghosted without resolution, then keep putting more work into even more questions. I've asked you to please hardcode strings for reproducibility rather than relying on process.argv. As with your last few questions, this code looks pretty much fine and works for me, so I suspect there's still missing context. Please share a [mcve].

It works. I've already provide the bash command line on how I call it. I don't consent to the stackoverflow policy of accepting answers. Good answers can be ranked. I don't think it is necessary to accept answers. there are too much bureaucracy on SO. Please stop asking.

If it works, then why are you asking a question? If you don't want to engage with anyone answering, what's the point of being a part of this community? Resolving your issues involves iteration, especially since your questions are basically working, and if there is a problem, you'll need to provide details and work with answerers. If you don't want to accept, that's fine, it's not a requirement that you do, but at least take the courtesy of following up with my answers and letting me know whether they resolve the issue or not, otherwise I'm sitting here waiting for follow ups that never happen.

No. I am saying it works to reproduce the problem. Not it works so that there is not any error.

It doesn't reproduce the problem, as is the case with your previous questions I can post yet another answer proving that the code is fine, but you'll probably ignore it like the others and keep spamming the site with new questions that are also missing reproducible details.

OK, I see your typo: const browser = await puppeteer.connect({browserURL}); should be browser = await puppeteer.connect({browserURL});. Please follow my provided boilerplate exactly.

If your run the program as described, it hangs there. What is wrong with that? I use browserURL as I don't want to waste time to start a new browser every time.

The problem is you're not taking the courtesy to follow my guidelines and answers I've provided so far, and this is the 4th question I've answered of yours today. connect is irrelevant to your problem--you can reproduce the issue with browser.launch() and hardcoded strings in a single file, which is much easier to reproduce than having to launch a persistent browser process to connect to. Still no package.json or version is listed, limiting the question's usefulness to future visitors.

OK. I find the bug. It should be fixed like this const browser -> browser. I typed an extra const.

Excellent, we've resolved an issue. Thanks for responding and working with me. Feel free to post in the other threads and confirm solutions there as well when you get the chance.

Always minimize your problems so you can be sure you've cleared away any red herrings and distractions and ensure you're asking about the right thing. Here's the minimal version of your actual issue:
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^22.7.1

let browser;
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  console.log("there");
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());

This is a simple scoping issue and has nothing to do with connect or waiting for elements to be removed.
When you use const browser, the let browser declared in the enclosing scope is never assigned anything and browser?.close() in the finally block is a no-op. But the real browser you launched inside the IIFE is never closed, causing the process to hang.
The solution is to remove the const so the variable binds to the correct outer scope:
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  console.log("there");
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());

